# Generate multiple files when creating one in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: file, intellij-idea

I want to create a file (in java), called `file.java`, then want to generate `file.in` and `file.out` after I do that. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91565) is coming in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (currently [available as EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/)).

[image: Template]